# How to store a string from user input in an array to perform search operation on it in C#?

Tags: c#

```
 public class CellPhoneMessagingController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/CellPhoneMessaging/{code}")]
        public string burgers(string code)
        {

          string userCode = code;
            char[] ch = new char[userCode.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < ch.Length; i++) { 
                    ch[i] = userCode[i];
            }

            return ch;

           
        }
    }
```

I tried this but it is not returning the ch. Note: I am new in programming.

Comment: You've declared the method return type as `string`, but you're returning a `char[]`.

Comment: all this code does is copy the input to the output, there is no searching. I assume this doesnt compile, to make it compile do `return new string(ch);`

Comment: the question is not api specific, please post a simple console application instead code snippet of  web api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to return the characters of the string as an array, then use [String.ToCharArray()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray?view=net-6.0):

```
public char[] burgers(string code)
{
    return code.ToCharArray();
}
```

Seems kinda pointless now to put that into a function, though...

Answer (score 1):

The return type has a problem. Your function should have a return type of string[].

```
 public class CellPhoneMessagingController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/CellPhoneMessaging/{code}")]
        public string[] burgers(string code)
        {

          string userCode = code;
            char[] ch = new char[userCode.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < ch.Length; i++) { 
                    ch[i] = userCode[i];
            }

            return ch;

           
        }
```

Comment: This is wrong. A `string[]` is not the right type here, nor is this what the OP wants.